# How do we call a function inside the Chrome content-script from "on-event" attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

How do we call a function which is in the Chrome addon content-script from on-event attribute such as "onmouseover=" whose element is either injected by codes lives in content-script itself or it's original in dom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content scripts run in an isolated world so they can't access page functions or JavaScript objects created by the page (like global variables in `window`). The opposite is also true, which is why it's called "isolated".

There are two solutions:

#### Dispatch a DOM event.

```
const el = document.querySelector('div[onmouseover]');
el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {bubbles: true}));
```

---

#### Run the code in the page context.

```
function runInPageContext(fn, ...params) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.textContent = 'document.currentScript.remove();' +
    `(${fn})(${JSON.stringify(params).slice(1, -1)})`;
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

Usage:

```
runInPageContext(selector => {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  el.onmouseover(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {bubbles: true}));
  // if you're sure the function doesn't use the event, call it directly:
  // el.onmouseover();
}, '*[onmouseover]');
```

Passing an element is impossible but here's a workaround:

```
// el is an element in DOM
const index = [...document.getElementsByTagName(el.tagName)].indexOf(el);
runInPageContext(index => {
  const el = [...document.getElementsByTagName(el.tagName)][index];
  el.onmouseover(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {bubbles: true}));
}, index);
```

Won't work as is in ShadowDOM, but that's a separate task.